# Proper way to iterate this?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of strings that are semicolon separated.

There will always be an even number because the first is the key, the next is the value,

**ex:**

```
name;Milo;site;stackoverflow;
```

So I split them:

```
 var strList = settings.Split(';').ToList();
```

But now I would like to use a foreach loop to put these into a `List<ListItem>`

I am wondering if it can be done via iteration, or if I have to use a value `'i'` to get `[i] and [i+1]`

Comment: I guess you can use easily use LINQ for this purpose. I'm no longer programming in C#, so not remembering the exact syntax, but I'm sure it is simple with LINQ in C#

Comment: You do plan to move this logic to a utility method, so the implementation detail (Linq, foreach, for, Split, whatever) doesn't matter and is trivial, right?

Comment: @Milo Be sure to check my answer below for the right way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a valuable helper function I use. It is similar to `GroupBy` except it groups by sequential indexes rather than some key.

```
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GroupSequential<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int groupSize, bool includePartialGroups = true)
    {
        if (groupSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("groupSize", groupSize, "Must have groupSize >= 1.");
        var group = new List<T>(groupSize);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            group.Add(item);
            if (group.Count == groupSize)
            {
                yield return group;
                group = new List<T>(groupSize);
            }
        }
        if (group.Any() && (includePartialGroups || group.Count == groupSize))
            yield return group;
    }
```

Now you can simply do

```
var listItems = settings.Split(';')
    .GroupSequential(2, false)
    .Select(group => new ListItem { Key = group[0], Value = group[1] })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Not me. morelinq has a [Batch](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) method doing this.

Comment: Their implementation actually has a flaw.  They have a required `resultSelector` parameter, and in the body of the methods they only ever call `yield return <something>;` if the `<something>` is a call to `resultSelector`. There is absolutely no reason to have that parameter included. If a user wants to transform the batches/groups, they can simply call `.Select(resultSelector)` immediately after the call to `Batch`.

Comment: I didn't inspect that code. But when thinking one of the Author is John Skeet, I don't think it has a flaw.

Comment: Better to take a look yourself at the "flaw" I'm identifying then to default to "Jon Skeet did it so it is pure gold." That `Batch` method certainly works correctly - it just combines two operations that (I think) shouldn't be combined.

Comment: That's because the utility extension method `GroupSequential` is very generic. The LINQ query to do what the OP wanted is only 4 simple lines.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with LINQ but I am not sure this one is better

```
var dict = input.Split(';')
            .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
            .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.First().s, x => x.Last().s);
```

You can also use [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s Batch for this

```
var dict2 = input.Split(';')
            .Batch(2)
            .ToDictionary(x=>x.First(),x=>x.Last());
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't compile this, but this should work for you:

```
var list = new List<ListItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < strList.Count; i++)
{
    i++;
    var li = new ListItem(strList[i - 1], strList[i]);
    list.Add(li);
}
```

again, I'm not in a position to fully recreate your environment but since the first is the key and second is the value, and you're sure of the state of the string, it's a pretty easy algorithm.

However, leveraging a `foreach` loop would still require you to know a bit more about the index so it's a little more straight forward with a basic `for` loop.

Comment: @Milo, have a look at the solution at the bottom and note that it's far from elegant with a `foreach`. That was my point. The solution below leverages a `bool` to ***infer*** the index.

Comment: better to use [i] in this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use foreach

```
string key=string.Empty;
    string value=string.Empty;

    bool isStartsWithKey=true;
    var strList = settings.Split(';').ToList()

    foreach(var item in strList)
    {
      if(isStartsWithKey)
      {
        key=item;
      }
      else
      {
        value=item;
        //TODO: now you can use key and value
      }

      isStartsWithKey=!isStartsWithKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int, string> yourlist;
for(int i=0;i<strList.length/2;i++)
{
  yourlist.add(new ListItem(strList[i*2], strList[i*2+1]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this seems to me to be the simpliest way

```
for(var i = 0; i < strList.Count(); i = i + 2){
    var li = new listItem (strList[i], strList[i + 1];
    listToAdd.Add(li);
}
```

**Updated Example**

```
for (var i = 0; i < strList.Count(); i = i + 2){

    if (strList.ContainsKey(i) && strList.ContainsKey(i + 1)){
        listToAdd.Add(new listItem(strList[i], strList[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The for loop will not cause an index out of bounds error like that. So what happens is on the first iteration, the var i is set to 0, the second it is set to 2 because the iteration counter is i = i + 2, the i < strList.Count() will evaluate to true and run the code, the third iteration the i is set to 4 which will evaluate to false and exit the for loop.

Comment: @KennethGarza it could if the number of items is odd, but according to the OP that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this is a simple example. In realty you should be doing a check to see if the index exists before attempting to access it.